# Vertex with completely different properties in Graphx Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, inheritance, spark-graphx

I'm struggling with implementing a property graph in Graphx where my vertexes have completely different properties. I am not able to apply inheritance method given in Spark documentation.

```
class VertexProperty()
case class UserProperty(val name: String) extends VertexProperty
case class ProductProperty(val name: String, val price: Double) extends VertexProperty
// The graph might then have the type:
var graph: Graph[VertexProperty, String] = null
```

Vertexes that I have includes `Recipe(name, cookingtime, serves)`, `Spice(name, quantity, measumentUnit)`, `Ingredient(name, quantity, type, usedIn)` and some more vertex.

I am trying to implement a property graph for recipes.

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with? You should be able to create a case class for each type (recipe/spice/ingredient/...) which all extends a common type (e.g. VertexProperty).

Comment: Thanks @Shaido, I misunderstood docs and mixed the concept of setting default values with this one. I successfully made graph and now having the problem with applying filters. When I apply filter like that `graph.vertices.filter case (id, (name, quantity,measurementUnit, UsedIn )) => name !="" }.foreach...`, it don't work.

Comment: That's hard to answer without more information about the code and the error. You could search for a similar question/create a new one here on the site.

Comment: @Shaido can you please help with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48212282/graphx-scala-applying-filter-on-vertex-with-property-inheritance