# Graphx Scala: Applying filter on Vertex with Property Inheritance

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I've vertices with different properties. Now I want to filter out those with a specific property value. Here's how my code looks like:

```
// Different property classes for different vertex
class VertexProperty()
case class Property1(val name: String, val servings: Int) extends VertexProperty
case class Property2(val description: String) extends VertexProperty
case class Property3(val name: String, val quantity: Double, val measurementUnit: String) extends VertexProperty

val vertexArray = Array(
    (1L, Property1("propertyName",8)),
    (2L, Property2("property description")),
    (3L, Property3("", 1,"lb."))
    )

 val edgeArray = Array(
     Edge(1L, 2L, "step1"),
     Edge(1L, 3L, "step2")
     )

 val vertexRDD: RDD[(Long, VertexProperty)] = sc.parallelize(vertexArray) 
 val edgeRDD: RDD[Edge[String]] = sc.parallelize(edgeArray)
 val graph: Graph[VertexProperty, String] = Graph(vertexRDD, edgeRDD)
```

Now I want to filter vertices, which property is `Property2` and whose description is not empty, I tried in these ways:

1. It's not giving expected result

   ```
   graph.vertices.filter { case (id, (descrition)) => descrition !="" }.foreach{
     case (id, (descrition)) => println(s"$descrition")
   }
   ```
2. This code is not working

   ```
   graph.vertices.filter { case (id, Property2(descrition)) => descrition !=""}.foreach{
     case (id, (descrition)) => println(s"$descrition")
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have tried is close but not exactly correct. You need two cases in the `filter`; one for the `Property2` and one for all other cases.

```
val vertices = graph.vertices.filter{
  case (id, vp: Property2) => vp.description != ""
  case _ => false
}
```

This will give you a `VertexRDD[VertexProperty]` with all the vertices that fulfill the requirements.